# Fastest way to get specific record in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I want to collect a specific Row in a Spark 1.6 DataFrame which originates from a partitioned HiveTable (the table is partitioned by a String column named `date` and saved as `Parquet`)

A record is unambiguously identified by `date`,`section`,`sample`

In addition, I have the following constraints

- `date` and `section` are Strings, `sample` is Long
- `date` is unique and the Hive table is partitioned by `date`. But
  there are maybe more than 1 files on HDFS for each `date`
- `section` is also unique across the dataframe
- `sample` is unique for a given `section`

So far I use this query, but it takes quite a long time to execute (~25 seconds using 10 executors):

```
sqlContext.table("mytable")
.where($"date"=== date)
.where($"section"=== section)
.where($"sample" === sample)
.collect()(0)
```

I also tried to replace `collect()(0)` with `take(1)(0)` which is not faster.